# Search records on block very slow oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have procedure in which enter Visit Number and search records on block. But this procedure search records take some time 3 to 4 minutes and block have 12672 records. How to optimize procedure to search records fast.

**CODE:**

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN
IF :CTRL_BLOCK.SRCH_VISITNO IS NULL THEN
     MESSAGE('Please enter Visit No...');
     GO_ITEM('SRCH_VISITNO');
ELSE
   BEGIN
         GO_BLOCK('cpvdtl');
         FIRST_RECORD;
         LOOP
             IF :cpvdtl.visitno = :CTRL_BLOCK.srch_visitno THEN
            exit;
         ELSE
            NEXT_RECORD;
         END IF;
       EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD='TRUE';
         END LOOP;
     EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            MESSAGE('No Data found...!');
     END;               
         END IF;
     :CTRL_BLOCK.srch_visitno := null;
go_item('cpvdtl.visitno');
END;
```

Comment: You don't normally search Forms blocks, which will be slow.  You normally search the database and display the results in a block.

Comment: @Tony Andrews When form open then records already shown on data block. Then specific no search on data block

Comment: yes, that s my point - there should be a search on the data block :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why reinventing the wheel?

Default Forms functionality works perfectly well, as simple as:

- create a block on a table
- run the form
- enter query mode
- enter search criteria into any column (wildcards included)
- execute query

If any record matches criteria, it will be displayed on the screen.

---

If you insist on your own search field, create it (which is what you already did). Then:

- I'd suggest you to create a push button
- create a `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger which will

  - utilize `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY` built-in, using the `ONETIME_WHERE` (or `DEFAULT_WHERE`; see which fits better) property, by setting the search field's value into the block's `where` clause
  - `EXECUTE_QUERY`

Why button and not only the search field? Because you'd then use `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger to `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY`, but you couldn't `EXECUTE_QUERY` in that trigger as it is a restricted procedure. Yes, you could use `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger, but - what if user navigates out of the search field using the mouse? That trigger wouldn't fire. I'd say that button is a simpler choice.

Comment: If the default WHERE just references the search field, you don't need to set the WHERE clause dynamically.

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you, @Andy.